# VBA: Do action if first cell in a word table has a certain value, otherwise go to next table

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to manipulate multiple Word tables through a VBA code from Excel. The Word document has multiple tables in it that need to be populated so I thought that I should make a code that goes through each table and identifies the first table that has the string "att" in the first cell (1,1). And if it does, then I would copy the cells from Excel into the specific table. After this is done, it would go to the immediate next table and paste from another location in the spreadsheet. This is the code I came up with so far, but the problem is that it's not recognizing the text in the cells of the tables so it goes until `i=30`. It just skips over the table that has "att" in the first cell. Any suggestions?

```vb
Sub UpdateTables()
    Dim documentname As String
    Dim aktDocument As Document
    Dim tbl As Word.Table
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim g As Integer
    Dim xWB As Workbook

    documentname = InputBox("Paste or Type the name of the cycle report word document")
    Documents(documentname).Select

    i = 1
   
    Do Until i > 30      ' Loop through each table in the document and stop when the first cell says attribute in it 
        Set aktDocument = ActiveDocument
        Set tbl = aktDocument.Tables(i)
    
        tbl.Select
    
        If tbl.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Att" Then ' Not recognizing text inside cell with this
            'Populate this graph and then populate the next few graphs with summary table info
            'Exit Loop below by making i = 31
            i = 31
        Else 'If first cell is not Att then end the if statement and loop again
        End If
       
        i = i + 1
    Loop
   
End Sub
```

Comment: `.Range.Text` of a table cell always ends with a [special character](https://superuser.com/q/1412060/52365). It will never compare equal to a string that does not also end with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't test for equivalence (=), instead test for the presence (Instr) of "Att" in Cell(1,1) of the Table.

```
Sub UpdateTables()
    
    Do
    
        Dim documentname As String
        documentname = InputBox("Paste or Type the name of the cycle report word document")
        
    Loop Until Len(documentname) > 0
    
    Dim myDoc As Word.Document
    Set myDoc = Documents(documentname)
    
    Dim myTable As Word.Table
    For Each myTable In myDoc.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory).Tables   ' Loop through each table in the document and stop when the first cell says attribute in it
    
        If InStr(myTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text, "Att") > 0 Then ' Not recognizing text inside cell with this
            
            Dim myWb As Excel.Workbook
            'Populate this graph and then populate the next few graphs with summary table info
            
            ' If you need to process additional tables before exiting the loop 
            ' not as part of the loop then 
            ' consider using the next method to get the next table in the document.
            ' Set myTable = myTable.Range.Next(unit:=wdTable)
            Exit For
            
        Else 'If first cell is not Att then end the if statement and loop again
        
        End If
        
    Next
   
End Sub
```

Comment: In the If statement, if I use the next method that you suggested for populating the next table, would it just loop the population action from the previous selected table? I am asking because the next tables get their data from different parts of my workbook.